# Initializing a command that's failing with popen

Tags: python

I am trying to run "RepoInitCmd" using Popen as below and running into following error..can any provide inputs on what is wrong?

```
import subprocess
Branch_Name='ab_mr2'
RepoInitCmd =  'repo init -u git://git.company.com/platform/manifest.git -b ' + Branch_Name
proc = subprocess.Popen([RepoInitCmd], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = proc.communicate()
```

ERROR:-

```
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen([RepoInitCmd], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Popen expects the command line to be passed as a list. In particular, the actual command that will be run (in this case 'repo') should be first item of the list.  Rather than writing commands as strings and using split or shlex to pass them to Popen as lists, I prefer to manage command lines as lists from the start, as this makes it easier to build the command line in code. So, in this case I might have written something like this:

```
RepoInitCmd = ['repo', 'init', '-u', 'git://git.company.com/platform/manifest.git']
RepoInitCmd.extend(['-b', Branch_Name])
proc = subprocess.Popen(RepoInitCmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note, if you want or need to pass a command line as a single string (perhaps to take advantage of shell features), then you can enable shell mode if you don't mind the additional overhead of running an extra shell process:

```
proc  = subprocess.Popen(RepoInitCmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(RepoInitCmd.split(" "), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

OR

```
import shlex
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(RepoInitCmd), stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You need to pass an array of arguments.  The first argument is treated as the binary name, so "repo init ..." is the name of the program it looks for.  You need to pass something like `["repo", "init", ...]`

Comment: or better use  `shlex.split`.